# No Shark on OS X Lion?

Tags: development, xcode

I can't find Shark on OS X Lion. The most recent Xcode is correctly installed, but I can only see Instruments. Has Shark been made obsolete by Instruments ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Correct.

Shark was replaced with Instruments. There is a set of tools from Apple called CHUD that does still include Shark.

It's available [here](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/8506/apple-chud-tools). It does require you to have a Developer Account to download. However there has been limited success in getting it to work on Lion.

It's safe to assume that Shark has bitten the dust.

Comment: Well, it's fine. Instruments is clearly a good replacement, it works well and it's less confusing. I used Shark just because I got used to it, but I won't miss it.

Comment: Hey - have you considered volunteering here to be a moderator? http://apple.stackexchange.com/election